# Resources for image representations of planetary systems that indicate the temperature of each part of the system

Tags: planetary-science, resource-request

I was wondering whether anyone knows a resource where I can get images in the form of illustrations or representations of planetary systems, where these images indicate or convey the temperature of each part of the system?  (e.g. [thermographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermography))

If not, Is there any resource where I can get images of planetary systems overall?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused by this request. Images don't show temperatures, but spectra. You fit a blackbody to a thermal spectrum, then you know the temperature of the emitting body. For directly imaged systems google "directly images exoplanet systems", assuming you talk about exoplanets. All other multiple systems are discovered by indirect methods (such as radial velocity, transit, transit timing variations..) and no images exist of them.

Comment: I am not strictly meaning images. I mean like thermal imaging or like "thermograms" but in astronomy.

Comment: You need an image at at least 3 different wavelengths to measure a temperature...

Comment: And even then you need to assume a black body radiator. That may or may not be a good approximation, depending on temperature, chemistry and choice of wavelengths.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question. Are you looking for "thermographs" such as the ones of the Earth in [this page](https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/global-temperature/) but for exoplanets? If this is the case, unfortunately this is not possible, because we don't have the resolution to see the surface of any exoplanet, nor to map its surface temperature